# Dallas transfer immigration stamps

Tags: esta, passport-stamps, connecting-flights

I recently noticed that on a transfer in Dallas Fort Worth that my passport was stamped on entry but not on exiting the airport. My arriving flight came from Sydney and my connection flight was to Cancun. I was only in the airport for about an hour and a half.

Should my passport have been stamped on exit of Dallas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The US doesn't stamp passports on exit. Your exit will have been recorded automatically when your boarding pass was scanned as you got on the plane. You can check your entry and departure record at the [CBP I-94 website](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/history-search).